# Backbone Marionette templateCache is not used by default?

Tags: templates, caching, backbone.js, marionette

According to Derick Bailey in one of his posts , *Template Cache Built In To Backbone.Marionette*

So when i specify a template like this

```
 Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({template : '#template1'});
```

Does it really store the template *template1* into template cache the first time  and access it from cache subsequently? 
I have this doubt because  when i inspect the global  TemplateCache object , it is not actually being stored. Am i missing something?

Is the template being selected from DOM each time?  (Derick even says *DOM Selection is expensive* )

I am a new to Marionette.Any help would be really appreciated.Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bt default, Marionette will read the DOM element and run it through underscore's template() function to compile the html template into a simple JS function.  This function is what goes in the template cache.  Take a look at the annotated source code available on the marionette site to see how this works and where you can plug in to change things.

Comment: thnx for your answer.it helped me. somebody else did it..i dont know why

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.templatecache.md
when you do this

```
var template = Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.get("#my-template");
```

inside your template var you will have a compiled template but at the same time this template will be stored in the cache, so the next time  you use that template the one form the cache will be used.

so you first need to use the templatecache object from marionette to compile/ store the template

Comment: so that means , by default marionette does not make use of template caching?

Comment: No, saying its built in it means that is already there not that is used by default.

Comment: It is used by default and without you needing to explicitly reference it